# laravel failed to load large data set from Datatbase

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a simple `Question` model with a **oneToMany** relationship to **itself** named `latest_sub_question` like this :

```
class Question extends Model

{
    useSoftDeletes;
    protected $primaryKey = 'question_id';

    public function latest_sub_question()
        {
        return $this->hasOne(Question::class , 'parent', 'question_id')->latest();

        }
}
```

`questions` table related to `Question` model have large dataset about **30k** records.

Now in a controller method I want to fetch all records(note that I want all and therefore I do not want to use `chunk` or **paginations** methods). For that I wrote this :

```
function questionsDatatable(Request $request)
    {
    $questions = Question::with('latest_sub_question');

    //Applies some constraint method on $questions here


    $questions = $questions->get();
   //Eloquent returns a query builder object and beacause I want to run `map` function should convert it to a collection.

    $questions = $questions->map(function ($item, $key)
        {
        return is_null($item->latest_sub_question) ? $item : $item->latest_sub_question;
        });

    $questions->sortByDesc('created_at');

    return $questions;

}
```

But it seems since `$questions` contains large data, laravel can not parse that and always does not return any things.

I do not understand what the problem ؟ what is your solution?

Comment: you can try increasing the `memory_limit` in `php.ini` but it'll be a better idea to paginate the result.

Comment: Yes as @shoieb0101 mentioned, I would not recommend passing back 30K records. Neither the client nor the server will be able to handle such loads. That's a design issue IMO.